# Use different subclass functions from base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Say now I have a base class, let's call it `GameEngine`. The `GameEngine` class inherited several functions from another class. Now I have several game states and I need to apply sub-class polymorphism to this problem: several game states all need to draw background of the game window. The point is, I must have only ONE class to initialise my game window. My problem is, when I need to change my game states from one to another, how can I do it? Essentially, how can I use different version of subclass function(say DrawBackground) from my superclass?

The code:

```
BaseEngine *gameEngine;

gameEngine = new MenuState(this);

iResult = gameEngine->Initialise(...); // To initialise the window

// I need to find a way to transfer my state from Menu to Play after the window is initialised

iResult = gameEngine->MainLoop(); // To refresh the window (in case of background changed)

gameEngine->Deinitialise();
```

So in the above code, I have a `BaseEngine` which can do several functions (draw something to the window). And I now have two game states, `MenuState` and `PlayState`. There is one virtual function in my `BaseEngine` called `DrawBackground()` and I need to redefine it(different behaviour) in my Menu and Play states. Now the point is only one state(whether Base, Menu or Play) can initialise the window. However I need it to use different version of my derived class (Menu and Play) to draw different background when state is changed.

Comment: Why are you using inheritance to model this?

Comment: @melpomene It's a given framework. The requirement is I must use it and can't change it. Any suggestions how I can do? I tried all methods I can come out, can't change the pointer address of game engine, so can't find a way of state transformation.

Comment: Don't know if it's just me, but it's unclear what you are asking for. What are "game states"? If `GameEngine` inherited several functions that makes it derived, not base. Do some classes derive from `GameEngine`? Please show some code

Comment: @Fureeish Added part of the code and some explanation, I hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you are asking but it feels like what you want is strategy pattern (that is, in simple words, changing some internal object/algorithm that does the job).

When dealing with inheritance, you should follow the so-called `is-a` relationship ([Wikipedia on Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming))). In your question, `GameEngine` is **not** a *state* (specifically `MenuState`).

What you should actually do is to implement the states as a strategy for `GameEngine` (See [Strategy Pattern on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), some, including me, call it **Policy Pattern** which is more self explanatory I think). You could have several classes inheriting from, say `BaseState`, and you should set these states on `GameEngine` via something like `GameEngine::setState(std::unique_ptr<BaseState> state)`. The `GameEngine` will act differently according to the strategy set on it. So in a simple case, we can say that `GameEngine::MainLoop()` will call the virtual `BaseState::draw()` function. So the data that gets drawn is simply controlled by the policy set on the `GameEngine` using `GameEngine::setState()`.

To put it simply, move the *behavior* to the `BaseState` strategy and change the strategy to change the behavior.

Optionally you could use some event mechanism to change the strategy (`state`). There is [Boost.Signal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/signals.html), Qt has its own and there are others but it is straightforward to implement one for simple needs, *easier* thanks to C++11.